# Any alternatives to CanvasRenderingContext2D on Java?

Tags: javascript, java, game-engine, renderer

I have a simple game written on JavaScript. Game's renderer uses CanvasRenderingContext2D. Now I wanna remake my game on Java, but i have a trouble.

Is there any alternatives to CanvasRenderingContext2D on Java? I need methods like ctx.save(), ctx.scale(), ctx.translation() and etc. I have tried to use Graphics2D, but it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Graphics2D` is roughly functionally equivalent to `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, so I'm not sure why you'd say `Graphics2D` is not a good solution.

If you don't want to use `Graphics2D` another alternative in Java is to use the JavaFX `Canvas` and `GraphicsContext`, also roughly functionally equivalent to rendering on HTML Canvas.

All these APIs do more or less the same thing (2D rendering) but, in my opinion, `Java2D/Graphics2D` is the best designed (particularly in the sense that the API is cleanly separated from the implementation, so you can easily change the target - for example, I have written `Graphics2D` subclasses that write output in SVG and PDF format without requiring any change in the calling code).